# How to safely remove git index lock?

Tags: git

I have a large git repo in which occasionally a git process crashes and left the index lock file, which needs to be remove manually
`rm -f ./.git/index.lock`

Is there a way to safely remove git index lock with an automatic cron job, by checking if there's no other git processes running?

Comment: Sure, you could do that.  But what if that process crashes?  Now you have two problematic systems to deal with.  Better to just delete the lock manually, or fix the original problem...prevent that occasional git process crash.  Or, wrap the git process execution in some outer process that will clean up after the git process if it crashes.  However you do it, I think that adding something that runs periodically to clean up a known problem rather than fixing that problem is the wrong way to go. - But that's just my opinion.  nothing particularly wrong with your solution.  Just not how I'd go.

Answer (score 4):

Don't automate that: if you do, you'll find it strikes just as you're trying to, say, make a commit, and removes your new index.<sup>1</sup>  (The `index.lock` file is used not only to lock the current index, but also to provide the *new* index that will *replace* the old one after any operation that causes the index to need updating.)

As [CryptoFool said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442207/how-to-safely-remove-git-index-lock#comment126275669_71442207), it's best to fix the original problem, whatever it may be.  Often that just means "upgrade your Git version".

---

<sup>1</sup>You said you'd "check that there is no Git process running", but this kind of checking is inherently racy.  Things always go wrong here ([Murphy's laws](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efgandon/miscellaneous/murphy/)).

Comment: Often that just means "upgrade your Git version" … and/or a fresh clone of the repository.